# Why can't the Python launcher import in a script (with shebang), when it works in the interpreter?

Tags: python, windows, shebang, path-variables

I'm using the `py` Python launcher, and something weird is happening with imports. Certain modules can't be imported in scripts - despite being installed with pip and being importable in the interpreter. Here's the kicker, though: it works in scripts without the shebang line.

For example, this script works:

```
import requests
```

But this one doesn't:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
```

Why is this? What difference is the shebang making here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `py` launcher actually [handles shebang lines even on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines). This means the Python version a script is run in may differ depending on the shebang line. For example, a shebang line of `#!/usr/bin/env python2` will always run Python 2, and `#!/usr/bin/env python3` will always run Python 3. Without a shebang line, `py` pretends the shebang is `!python`, which it handles using [its **built-in rules for selecting a Python version**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) (see the *Python Version Qualifiers* section). By default, if you have it installed, this will be some version of Python 2.

Here's what's tripping you up, though. If the shebang is specifically `!/usr/bin/env python`, **`py` instead [follows the PATH environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)** to mimic the behavior of Linux's `env` (see the last paragraph), and only after that falls back on the normal behavior. This means scripts with the shebang *might* be running under a different Python version than `py` normally invokes, depending on what's in your PATH. This is what's happening here - `#!/usr/bin/env python` is finding another Python version on the path, and using that instead. That version might not have the modules you `pip install`ed installed, and might therefore fail.

Since you're using `py`, you shouldn't have a `python` on your PATH, so **remove any Python base directory entries from your PATH** (e.g. `C:\Python35`), or make sure the first Python on the PATH is the default one used by `py`, and everything should work just fine.

Why `py` doesn't try to follow the path by default (or when the shebang is `!python`), however, is anyone's guess.

Comment: Of the supported virtual commands, only `/usr/bin/env python` is defined to search `Path` -- and only when there's no version spec, i.e.  `#! /usr/bin/env python3` will not search `Path` for `python3.exe` (someone filed a bug about this recently, so it may change in a future release).  As to just `python`, it's a virtual command that doesn't search `Path`.

Comment: As to not having `python` in `Path`, that's fine and the default behavior of the installer. But `python` is still the official way to run the interpreter that you'll see in tutorials. Using `py` at the command line is convenient, but only available on Windows.

Comment: @eryksun Yep, I covered that in the answer. "If the shebang is **specifically** `!/usr/bin/env python`[...]". I'm also well aware that `!python` is a "virtual command" for `py` - I've read through the source code. The last paragraph questions why the decision was made, not why the launcher expresses that behavior.

Of course this answer is about the Windows `py` launcher - the question specifies as much.

Comment: @eryksun When I had this problem, I had just updated Python to 3.5 - turns out the installation was set to adding it to the PATH (guess I checked the box thinking it meant the launcher, maybe).

Comment: You were the one who wondered why `!python` doesn't search `Path`. I told you that it's simply not designed this way. There's nothing deep or fundamental to wonder about. In fact, in the first few iterations even `/usr/bin/env python` didn't search `Path`. That was added later, even though Vinay had coded the underlying support for it in the first release.

Comment: As to running Python via py.exe, yes this is a Windows question, but using `py` on the command line is not officially recommended (it's come up in various conversations), and the installer has an option to add Python's installation directory to `Path` specifically for people that want to run "python" as shown in almost every tutorial.

Comment: @eryksun Ah, you seem to be misunderstanding - the question is *why* it's designed that way. Also... I find it odd `py` wouldn't be recommended, as it's part of the Python 3 installer and the official documentation. Hmm. Oh, and you really don't need to explain to me why there's an "add to path" option for the main Python executable.

Comment: Apparently I do need to explain why the add-to-path option is there if you don't see that py.exe isn't the officially recommended way to run Python. Otherwise we wouldn't have the option and would just tell people to run py.exe on Windows -- which would isolate Windows users, who are by far the minority in the Python community. I was never in favor of naming it "py.exe" but rather making a smarter "python.exe" launcher that could operate in both modes. But it is what is, and I can't change it.

Comment: As to the `python` virtual command, I always understood that you're asking "why", and I explained the context that at first even `/usr/bin/env python` didn't search `Path`. The behavior was changed *much* later by Paule Moore, IIRC. Originally it only ran registered versions of Python for any "python" command, and was designed to prefer the latest available version of Python 2 for non-versioned virtual commands, for compatibility with Unix. We're changing this behavior when just running `py.exe` at the command line (not virtual commands) to instead prefer Python 3.

Comment: @eryksun So what is the rationale behind not trying to do the path search by default, too (falling back on the current approach)? Just inertia? Apparently the way it works now was very confusing to at least one person.

Comment: The recent bug report that I mentioned was because `/usr/bin/env python3` doesn't search for python3.exe. It will search for anything that doesn't start with "python", but it will only search for a non-versioned "python" command.  I suppose since there isn't a history of using versioned executable names on Windows that it wasn't considered worth searching. But this should be changed because clearly some people do manually copy/link versioned names on Windows.

Comment: @eryksun I can't believe I'm back to this, but here I go... Now I've suddenly got a script with the `#/usr/bin/env python` shebang line, but it launched Python 2. `py` launches Python 3.6, and I have no Python executables anywhere in my path. What's up?

Comment: If `python` isn't found in `Path`, then `#!/usr/bin/env` (you have an exclamation, i.e. bang, right?) handles it as a virtual shebang, finding a suitable version in the registry. In this case `python` prefers Python 2 if it's installed, which is designed for compatibility with Unix. In 3.6 `py` on the command line was changed to prefer the highest installed version.

Comment: @eryksun Is that so... So `#!/usr/bin/env python` always chooses Python 2 when there's no Python on the path, huh. It also chooses Python 2 when I add Python 3 to the path, however. How come?

Comment: It works for me. Running shebang.py containing just the line `#!/usr/bin/env python -V` prints "Python 3.6.0" when I have Python 3 in `Path`. I added it in the current command prompt using `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Python36"`. Normally I only have `python` in `Path` for an active virtual environment.